# Win32 ::shutdown() returns -1, but WSAGetLastError() returns 0?

Tags: winapi, winsock2

In porting some working unit tests from Linux to Windows I'm running across a strange problem. It appears that when my tests go to shutdown the server socket, shutdown() returns -1, but WSAGetLastError() returns 0 (and getsockopt( with SO_ERROR ) returns 0, and GetLastError() returns 0 )... So, shutdown() tells me there is an error, but all of the normal calls to see what that problem was are returning "no problem!"... Has anyone ever seen this before?

The code that calls shutdown looks like this:

```
int ret = ::shutdown( _sok, mode );
if( ret < 0 )
    X_THROW(( XSDK::ModuleId, XSDK::F_OS_ERROR, "Unable to shutdown socket."));
```

When I catch the exception, I call all those GetLastError() functions... Does throwing reset the last errors?

Comment: Can you post the code? Just wondering you you have a check like `if (error = SOCKET_ERROR)`...

Comment: What does `X_THROW` do? If it makes some other system call, that could reset the error code.

Comment: Looking at X_THROW(), I don't see it doing anything that could clear the error... It just logs the error through our logger (which on windows, writes a message to a file) and then creates an exception object and throw's it... our exception object inherits from std::exception..

Comment: @dicroce: "writes a message to a file" - that counts as a system call, and that is likely resetting the error code. You need to call `GetLastError` or `WSAGetLastError` before *any* other system call.

Comment: I went ahead and rebuilt the library with the shutdown() call... I added a call to WSAGetLastError() right before the X_THROW and sure enough, I got back 10057... So the question is... What causes the error code to be cleared? Any system call?

Comment: Yes, just about any system call will reset the error code. And since most standard library calls eventually make a system call, they too will indirectly reset the error code. That's why you must retrieve the code immediately.

Comment: @casablanca you should write this up as an answer so you can get the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ended up being that nearly any system calls can clear Win32's "LastError()" errors... In my case, throwing an exception meant formatting and logging a message, which caused the error to be clear... And even though I was calling WSAGetLastError() immediately in my catch(...) it was already too late...